# using NetworkLobbyManager with dynamic NetworkStartPositions

Tags: unity-game-engine

Having some trouble getting the NetworkLobbyManager to honor my NetworkStartPositions. This stems from the fact I generate my board dynamically when the game scene is loaded in my GameManager object.

I tried disabling auto spawn in the NetworkLobbyManager but it prevents LobbyPlayers from spawning too.

I would move my GameManager or NetworkStartPosition Spawner up into the Lobby scene but that doesn't seem like the right answer.

Here's where I am in my project: https://github.com/jakecoffman/tanks-unity/tree/f397b8b4e494461b94c718f1997d7572e5c6821f

Any suggestions? Any other tips on my project are welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someone else's project on Github that overrides `OnLobbyServerSceneLoadedForPlayer` and sets the position of the game player. Still not sure how to use NetworkStartPosition, but this is simple enough!